# Count #of times an item is "reblogged"

Tags: mysql, sql

If somebody can suggest a better title for this thread after reading that will help others with a similar problem I'll amend it.

I'm trying to count vicarious reblog numbers on my website, which currently only counts organics.

e.g.

USER1 uploads an image,
USER2 reblogs the image

It now displays the reblog count as "1" on USER1's image page.

Here lies the problem.

If another user, USER3 for example, reblogs USER2's image. The count on the original uploader remains at 1.  Despite USER1's image being shared twice. It only counts organic reblogs.

People are therefore able to exploit less popular users who upload popular images and take all the credit.

Here is the SQL details:

When an image is "reblogged", it automatically adds the following details to a table named `reblog`:

`id`
`repin_user_id`
`owner_user_id`
`from_pin_id`
`new_pin_id`

Using my above example, `repin_user_id` would be USER2. `owner_user_id` would be USER1. `from_pin_id` would be the page where USER2 reblogged the image from and `new_pin_id` would be the new page where USER2's reblogged image appears.

Is there any way I could count the vicarious reblogs for a particular image?
there is also a `timestamp` column in the `reblog` table.

Comment: Couldn't people just get around other methods by download the image, renaming it and then uploading it again?

Comment: Yes they could do this and there is nothing to stop them, but I encourage users to share from one another and to report stolen images - accusations which can be confirmed by comparing timestamps in the database. I only reward users for sharing from each other using a points system - which they can use to acquire new features on the site.

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in your database design and the way you process data.  You will need an item table.  It will contain fields such as item_id, created_when, create_by, etc.

Then, when I am the first person to submit that item, it gets an item_id.  For the sake of a value, let's give it one - 47.   A record goes into the item table and my blog data will show an item_id of 47.  Note that if a blog can have more than one item, you will need to set up a many to many relationship.

Next, when Bloggins reblogs my item, his blog data will also show item_id = 47.  And, when Buddy reblogs Bloggins's item, his data will show item_id = 47.

Finally to count the number of reblogs it's a simple query of

```
 select count(*) -1 reblogs
 from where_ever
 where item_id = 47
```